# why will jquery not put results in div with background color set

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu containing onclick calls. Then my js script catches the data and sends it to a php script for processing and returns it back to my js script which is supposed to place the results into the defined document element. Simple enough, right.

For some reason though, if I set the background color in my css the results will not show. Here are the relevant parts of my code. Can someone point out to me if there is a flaw in my code; and if not, why does this behavior happen and is there a work around.

My css...

```
    .decade { margin-left: 150px; padding: 20px; color: green; }
    .slaby { position: fixed; left: 200px; bottom: 86px; top: 50px; right:50px; color: black; padding: 20px; background-color: #ddd; border: 2px solid grey; }
```

My html...

```
     <div class='tln'>
      <span class='point' onclick='mes(this)' go='a' >The 70's</span>
      <span class='point' onclick='mes(this)' go='b' >The 80's</span>
     </div>
     <div id='decade' class='decade'>
     <div id='slab' class='slaby'></div>
     </div>
```

My js...

```
    function mes(span) {
    var clam = span.getAttribute('go'); var shot = 1;
     $.ajax({ url:'', type:'POST',
        data:{ page: clam, shoot: shot, },
          success: function(snowy){
           $('#slab').html(snowy);
           $('#decade').html(snowy);}});}
```

In my js script I am placing the results in both 'slab' and 'decade' elements just for testing purposes. Now with my css the way that it is, div(decade) is showing the results, while div(slab) is still blank.

For some reason: if I remove the background color from the div(slab) The results show here; if I add a background color to the div(decade) the results still show here.

I'm looking for a way to display the results in div(slab); as well as, having css style div(slab)'s background color. Thank you all for any help and have a great day.

Comment: Have you checked with the browser's document inspector to make sure the element really does not contain the updated content? The style of the element won't affect how jQuery `.html()` works, but something might be making the element invisible.

Comment: Yes. div(decade) contains the results; while, div(slab) contains nothing.

Comment: Or you can go to the browser's console after the content should be there and  type `$("#slab").html()` and see what it says.

Comment: #slab is a child of #decade. When you put snowy into #decade, you remove #slab

Comment: yes that's definitely the problem. You're missing the `</div>` for the "decade" block.

Comment: I have tried it without placing results in div(decade); though, to no avail.

Comment: I don't understand why results will show in both divs when I take the background color out of my css.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid; is that not clear? The browser is interpreting your markup as having the "slab" element *inside* the "decade" element. Because of that, when you update the content of "decade" everything inside it — including the "slab" element — is completely replaced by the new content. That means the "slab" element just goes away completely.

Comment: Actually it's not invalid; the indentation confused me. But it's definitely the case that "slab" is inside of "decade".

Comment: Perhaps you changed something when you changed your CSS, but this has *nothing* to do with the background color.

Comment: I have completely taken div(decade) out of my html, css, and js codes and the results are the same. Nothing shows in the div with background color set.

Comment: If you really don't want to change decale html so remove code $('#decade').html(snowy); So I hope you will get the desired output

Comment: I did already. still no results. I feel it has something to do with another property in the css.

Comment: I found a solution. See answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(SOLVED) why will jquery not put results in div with background color set.

I am not sure why the query contents were not being displayed, but changing the style for div(slab) with a z-index provided the results I was looking for.

I set the z-index for div(slab) to `z-index: -1;` and 'voila', works perfect.

```
    .slaby { position: fixed; left: 200px; bottom: 86px; top: 50px; right:50px; color: black; padding: 20px; z-index: -1; background-color: #ddd; border: 2px solid grey; }
```

I have no idea why this works because no other element inside or outside of it has a z-index set.

Thank you all for your input and effort. I hope this solution helps somebody.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the other comments pointed out that #slab is "inside" of #decade so when you are doing $('#decade).html() you are replacing/removing #slab.

Use

```
$('#decade').append()
```

instead or alternatively

```
$('#decade').prepend()
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but this did not solve the problem.